# CORS prefetch error in python pyramid application

Tags: python, pyramid

I have a webapp front end built in reactjs and calling a api built using python pyramid.

When I test this application in local development, I deploy the webapp in localhost:6543 and python application in localhost:3000.

I get a CORS prefetch error while calling the python application.

Here is my JS call -

```
const onFinish = (values) => {
    fetch(`${baseUrl}login`, {
      method: "POST",
      mode: 'no-cors',
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:3000",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(values),
```

Python application adding cors header -

```
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from invest_web.authentication.security import SecurityPolicy
from pyramid.response import Response
from pyramid.events import NewRequest
from invest_web.models.models import User, Issuer

def add_cors_headers_response_callback(event):
    def cors_headers(request, response):
        
        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST,GET,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS'
        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'access-control-allow-origin,content-type'
        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'        
    event.request.add_response_callback(cors_headers)

def main(global_config, **settings):
    """ This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application.
    """
    with Configurator(settings=settings) as config:
        config.include('pyramid_jinja2')

        config.set_security_policy(
            SecurityPolicy(
                secret=settings['invest_web.secret']
            ),
        )

        config.add_subscriber(add_cors_headers_response_callback, NewRequest)
        config.include('.routes')
        config.include('.models')
        config.scan()

    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It says `404 Not Found` when doing `OPTIONS` request.

My guess is that your event handler is not called unless a view is found, but I might be wrong.